# PyQt print QWidget

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt4, qpainter, qprinter

Am trying to follow the documentation for [printing a QWidet](https://doc.qt.io/archives/qt-4.8/printing.html) and am getting an error. When I run the following code I get `QPaintDevice: Cannot destroy paint device that is being painted`.

```
import sys
from PyQt4 import QtGui, QtCore

class SampleApp(QtGui.QDialog):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        layout = QtGui.QVBoxLayout()
        self.setLayout(layout)

        text_editor = QtGui.QTextEdit()
        layout.addWidget(text_editor)

        button = QtGui.QPushButton("Print")
        layout.addWidget(button)
        button.clicked.connect(self.print_me)

    def print_me(self):
        printer = QtGui.QPrinter()
        printer.setOutputFormat(QtGui.QPrinter.PdfFormat)
        printer.setOutputFileName("Test.pdf")

        self.painter = QtGui.QPainter(printer)
        margins = printer.getPageMargins(QtGui.QPrinter.DevicePixel)
        xscale = (printer.pageRect().width() - margins[0]) / self.width()
        yscale = (printer.pageRect().height() - margins[1]) / self.height()
        scale = min(xscale, yscale)
        self.painter.scale(scale, scale)

        self.render(self.painter)

app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
ex = SampleApp()
ex.show()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

If I change the print_me() method to the following, it does however work (I just lose all of the ability to scale the painter of course):

```
def print_me(self):
    printer = QtGui.QPrinter()
    printer.setOutputFormat(QtGui.QPrinter.PdfFormat)
    printer.setOutputFileName("Test.pdf")

    self.render(QtGui.QPainter(printer))
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

QPainter for optimization does not apply all the tasks at the same time but it keeps instructions and applies them at the end but to force that task it is better to call the end() method or delete with it since the destroyer also calls end(), in addition it is not necessary for QPainter to be a member of the class:

```py
def print_me(self):
    printer = QtGui.QPrinter()
    printer.setOutputFormat(QtGui.QPrinter.PdfFormat)
    printer.setOutputFileName("Test.pdf")

    painter = QtGui.QPainter(printer)
    xscale = printer.pageRect().width() / self.width()
    yscale = printer.pageRect().height() / self.height()
    scale = min(xscale, yscale)
    painter.translate(printer.paperRect().center())
    painter.scale(scale, scale)
    painter.translate((self.width() / 2) * -1, (self.height() / 2) * -1)

    self.render(painter)
    painter.end()
    # or
    # del painter
```

Comment: Well I would have certainly never thought of that.